# Getting outline of a graph as a polygon in PyGame

Tags: python, geometry, pygame

I have a feeling that this is impossible (or at least very complicated), but I currently have a generated graph that looks something like this (excuse my terrible paint skills):

[image]

Now, I'd like to be able to create a polygon of the outline, I have the coordnates of all the nodes, but not the intersections. The best I can manage so far is the Gift Wrapping algorithm, which gives more of a rough outline of the polygon than anything else.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could go about this?

(I'm currently using PyGame)

Comment: how about encompasing the whole surface in a rectangle and doing a custom floodfill? If you don't need the actual points, this might be the easiest way

Comment: Good suggestion, but I do need the points, unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to figure out where intersections happen and make new nodes there.

Then you want to find an edge that's on the outer polygon.  I suggest running a random ray in from infinity until it strikes an edge.

Then imagine yourself walking along that edge, keeping your left hand on the boundary and your right hand outside.  Start walking.

When you hit a node, you turn, such that you don't cross any edge.  That is, you begin to traverse the next edge in counterclockwise order.  (A simple implementation of this would be to sort them by direction, using atan2().)

It's all basic high school algebra and trigonometry, but it might be a little rough if this is your first time programming anything of this nature.  You'll learn a lot, though.

Comment: Hmm, I figured it would be something along those lines. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a name for this type of graph problem? I've been searching, but most of the algorithm outline a set of points.